# How do I keep Azure Functions v2 runtime running in a container after an assembly reference change?

Tags: docker, azure-functions-runtime

Following Azure Functions runtime v2 container definitions available on Docker Hub and GitHub I start the runtime with

```
CMD ["dotnet", "C:\\runtime\\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.dll"]
```

When accessing certain functions log shows "Assembly reference changes detected" and stops the host...

```
> docker logs {id}
info: Function.GraphQuery[0]
     Assembly reference changes detected. Restarting host...
....
info: Host.General[0]
      Environment shutdown has been triggered. Stopping host and signaling shutdown.
....
info: Host.General[0]
      Stopping Host
info: Host.Startup[0]
      Job host stopped
```

and the container is gone:

```
> docker ps {id}
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS  NAMES
```

What do I need to adapt to keep the container running after a reference change?

Comment: Problem has been fixed or disappeared with release 2.0.11888-alpha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been fixed or disappeared with release 2.0.11888-alpha